# Assigning a pointer to a array of pointers to char

Tags: c, pointers

gcc 4.4.4 c89

```
#define SIZE 5
    char *names[SIZE] = {"peter", "lisa", "simon", "sarah", "julie"};
    char *search_names[SIZE] = {0};
    size_t i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ ) {
        search_names[i] = names[i]++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("name to search for [ %s ]\n", search_names[i]);
    }
```

I am confused about this line `search_names[i] = names[i]++;` Which is a array of pointers to char*. Just my experimenting I was thinking that it should be `&names[i]++`. Because I want to get the pointer at that location. So having the & would get me the address of where the pointer is pointing.

I guess I could increment as well like this: `(names[i]) + i`;

Just confused about that line.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand the intent of your code. Both of those arrays are arrays of pointers to char. Are you just copying one array to the other? In that case it ought to just be "search_names[i] = names[i];". Why do you need to increment at all?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was just experimenting and trying different things. However, search_names[i] = names[i]; produces the same result as search_names[i] = names[i]++; Does this mean they are both equal in a sense. What would names[i]++ be incrementing? Thanks.

Comment: names[i] refers to some character string like "peter". In C, character strings are stored as character arrays, terminated by a "\0". When you grab names[i], you are actually grabbing a pointer to the first element in the string which is sitting at names[i], in other words, a pointer to "p" in "peter\0".  When you increment that pointer, it moves forward one space, to pointing at "e", to make "eter\0". The increment is happening after the assignment to search_names[i], though, because of the obscure precedence rules, so it looks identical, but you are performing an additional pointer operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`names[i]` is a pointer, having type `char*`. `&names[i]` is a pointer to `names[i]`, and hence has type `char**`. A picture of some memory:

```
names                    for each i, this is where names[i] *points*
|__________________          0     1    2     3     4
|                  |         |     |    |     |     |
|                  |         v     v    v     v     v
[0 ][1 ][2 ][3 ][4 ]  <gap>  peter0lisa0simon0sarah0julie0
        ^
        |_This is where &names[2] points, i.e. this is where names[2] *is*
```

`name` is an array of 5 pointers, and I've depicted each pointer with square brackets and its index. Plus a space, because pointers are 4 byte on my machine. This is the situation just after `names` has been initialised. The separate chunk of memory on the right is a sequence of bytes, with each `0` indicating a 0 / NUL byte, not the character `0`. It's the responsibility of the implementation (compiler, linker and loader working together) to assign memory for string literals - I have assumed that all of the string literals you've used will be clustered together, although that needn't be the case. Finally, the numbers 0 ... 4 indicate where each pointer in `names` is pointing to.

Since you're assigning to a `char*`, you need a `char*`. Or looking at it another way, pointers point to the same thing if (and only if) the pointers themselves have the same value. So if you want `search_names[i]` (which is a pointer) to point to the same thing that `names[i]` points to, then `search_names[i] = names[i]` is exactly right.

I don't know what the intent is of doing `names[i]++`, though. It modifies the pointer `names[i]`. Modifying a pointer makes it point to a different thing. In this case you'll end up with `names[0]` pointing to "eter", `names[1]` pointing to "isa", and so on.

Here's what memory looks like after you've incremented each pointer in `names`:

```
names                
|_____________           0     1    2     3     4
|             |          |     |    |     |     |
v             v          v     v    v     v     v
[0][1][2][3][4]         peter0lisa0simon0sarah0julie0
```

By the way, you're *allowed* to assign a string literal to `char*`, but that doesn't mean you *should*. It would be better to declare your arrays `const char *names[SIZE]`. It's undefined behaviour to modify the memory which the compiler has assigned for a string literal, and using a `const char*` rather than a `char*` helps enforce that.

Answer (score 2):

names[] is defined as an array of pointers to chars.  Therefore, names[i] is a pointer to the ith string contained in names.  search_names[] is an array of pointers to char as well and therefore, search_names[i] is a pointer as well.  Therefore there is no need to apply the address operator to names[i] to get search_names[i] to point to the same string as names[i] does.  Hope this clarifies things for you.

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to copy the array names into search_names? Do note that names and search_names are both pointers to characters. IE, names[i] is a pointer.

The expression

```
search_names[i] = names[i]
```

Assigns the value of search_names[i] to be names[i]. This is simply putting the content on the runtime stack at address &names[i] into the cell at address &search_names[i]. In this case, it's copying just a pointer. It will NOT copy the characters. It will ONLY copy the content from the cell names[i]--the pointer to the first character of a sequence of characters.

The reason why

```
search_names[i] = names[i]++;
```

is equivalent to

```
search_names[i] = names[i]
```

in the context of search_names is because the increment operator affects the value of names[i]. It has a lower precedence AFTER the assignment operator. So the expression will increment names[i] after the assignment. Since names[i] is a pointer, the increment does some pointer arithmetic, which means it will point to address (names[i] + sizeof(char) ).